# How to indicate the current progress of querying a large dataset?

Tags: c#, sql, progress-bar

I want to use progress bar to show the current progress % the rows of data have been loaded.  I see [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135650/show-progress-of-filling-a-dataset-from-mysql) has been asked in SO, but the solution is just suggest using marquee style.

For example, I run a Select statement that query a large data table which might take few seconds.
I want the progress bar update the current progress of the query.  Is that possbile?

I know there is few things I need:

1. A count of total records will be retrieving.  (Can obtain by Select count(1) first)
2. Some notificiation to tell how many records I just retrieved.

For 2. is the part I don't know how to implement.

I can think of split it into couples query, but this may not be possible all the time.

But how about something similiar to `Cursor` in SQL?  Ask SQL Server to query a chunk and returns data and repeatly.

```
for loop{
    //query a chunk of records

    //return 

    //Next
}
```

So I can caculate the progress and fill them into a single `DataTable`.

Is it possible to do something above? If so, how?

Because I seen an ASP.NET applicateion able to show the progress of loading a large data table, so I want to implement the same thing in WPF.

Comment: What do you use for data access: ORM, web services, ADO.NET etc? What is your backend server?

Comment: @oleksii I am using Entity Framework, but I think this maybe diffcult with ORM.  So I am thinking to use ADO.NET to implement this with SQL Server.

Comment: @KingChan, are you sure having a progress bar is worth not using ORM?

Comment: @oleksii Actually for the module I am implementing is have to use ADO.NET anyway.  It required to run a dynamic SQL Statement that the user define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to be certain breaking the query into two isn't going to double your querying time. You may find yourself waiting a couple of seconds before you get the record count, and you haven't solved anything.

You *could* execute both queries in parallel (databases love concurrency and handle it very well), but you'll be putting an extra burden on the database, which could become a scalability issue in the future.

As for querying in chunks, I believe the `SqlDataReader` will allow you to fetch records as they become available, without first waiting for the entire query to complete. You'll have to add them to the DataTable yourself, though.

Comment: +1 I choose this as answer, becasue it fits my question the most.

Answer (score 2):

If you are loading the entire table in memory, you might doing it wrong. Does the user really need all that data? How many users will query the database at the same time? Are you sure the user will work with the whole table?

If you answered *yes* to all these question than you can consider using a pagination pattern: **Skip** + **Take** and you can rise a progress update event with the skip/take/total values.

```
//META CODE
var dataTable = new List<DataTable>(); //in-memory storage
int rowCount = [...].Rows.Count(); //this is fast check with database
int current;

while (current < rowCount)
{
  var fetchedData = [...].Skip(current).Take(1000).ToList();
  dataTable.AddRange(fetchedData);
  current = dataTable.Rows.Count();

  //fire progress update event
}
```

Comment: this is how you access your actual database, either through EF, or SqlDataReader or anything else (please excuse my syntax, this is just to show an idea)

Answer (score 1):

If you query the count of you current dataset it will iterate through all rows. That's nearly as slow as just fetching it. You could try to select a count by sql statement.
eg:`"SELECT COUNT(ID_COLUMN) FROM TABLE WHERE ..."`. That's another sql statement you have to execute but faster as asking the dataset for it's count.
There is a C# progressbar control. You just need to set a maximum value and each time you iterate your loop you can call function step(). It will set the progressbar one step ahead ;)
No need for you to do percentage calculation.

Comment: +1. This solves the "download i millsion rows takes ages" problem, not the "query is slow". Contrary- it hits the server twice with tehe heavy query. People get fired for that kind of optimization.

Comment: As far as I know that's the best way to use a progressbar with sql datasets. I'm looking forward to learn a better solution!

Comment: @gimbar Can you elaborate what do you mean by `select a count by sql statement`?